# How to find nodes that don't have certain child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I could not find the exact question answered on this site.
The html on the page has many  elements, some of them contain header cells "tr", some actual data cells "td"

Here is an example:

```
<tr align="center">
    <th width="63"><b>&nbsp;</b></th>
    <th width="293"><b>Partners</b></th>
    <th width="54"><b>Score</b></th>
    <th width="184"><b>Type of Partner</b></th>
</tr>            
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td height="17">Acme trucking</td>
 <td align="center">0.75</td>
 <td>Truck Carrier</td>
</tr>
```

I need to find all "tr" elements that contain only "td" elements, in other words, exclude all that contain "th" elements

I would also like to have even more specific xpath expression that will find only "tr" elements that contain exactly 4 "td" child elements.

If you can provide 2 separate xpath expressions for just trs that have only "td"
and another one for "tr" that have exactlly 4 "td" I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `//tr[td and count(td) = count(*)]` or `//tr[td and not(*[not(self::td)])]`
2. `//tr[count(td) = 4 and count(td) = count(*)]`

If you need `tr` with `td` only and without text, e.g.:

```
<root>
    <tr>
        Text here
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</root>
```

Suppose, it is not valid `tr`, you can use:

```
//tr[td and count(td) = count(*) and not(normalize-space(text()))]
```

It allows only whitespaces.

Comment: Hm, not currently in a position to test, but does that indeed disregard the whitespace nodes between the td's?

Comment: @Wrikken, What is "whitespace nodes"?

Comment: @kirill: the enters / tabs / spaces between the `<td>` elements are officially textnodes, with only whitespace in them. But I don't know whether `*` captures them or not. I suspect not (and then your example works fine), but I'm not sure

Comment: @Wrikken, `*` matches any node. In answer context it means: any child (not descendant) node.

Comment: @kirill: I've had time to test now, according to [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) `*` does _not_ match any node, but in this context any _element_ (so no textnodes, attributenodes). Which makes your answer to the OP correct, but _"`*` matches any node"_ is just wrong. Compare: http://pastebin.com/BKPkBGmV

Comment: @Wrikken, `* selects all element children of the context node`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Comment: @kirill: it's just a matter of semantics, all `element`s are `node`s, but not all `node`s are `element`s, I think that's where our communication broke down :)

Answer (score 1):

*I need to find all "tr" elements that contain only "td" elements, in other words, exclude all that contain "th" elements*

```
//tr[not(th)]
```

*I would also like to have even more specific xpath expression that will find only "tr" elements that contain exactly 4 "td" child elements.*

```
//tr[count(td) = 4]
```

This is assuming that any single `tr` will not have both `td` and `th` children.

Comment: @Kirill, I'm not sure I understand your comment. I think you're saying that my XPaths are not as general as yours? I believe mine are  correct, under reasonable interpretations of the OP's questions. If you disagree, please give details.

Comment: I agree with you, mostly by the first XPath. I think @Kirill is referring to your assumption about tr with only td or th, which is absolutely reasonable +1. However HTML tables may have td and th mixed up in the same row.